# Django Admin - how to forbid to create already existing object

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
CATS = (
    ('CT', 'Cool Things'),
    ('II', 'Internet & IT'),
    ('BT', 'Beautiful Things'),
)
cat = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATS)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.get_cat_display()
```

I have created objects to all three categories. Now I want to forbid my co-workers to create another object which already exists. How is it possible? I googled but cannot seem to have found something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `unique=True` for a `cat` field ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique)):

> This is enforced at the database level and by model validation. If you
>   try to save a model with a duplicate value in a unique field, a
>   `django.db.IntegrityError` will be raised by the model’s `save()` method.

```
cat = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATS, unique=True)
```